# Asana API Query Error "Empty Field Name"

Tags: c++, rest, asana

I am starting to write the Asana API using Embarcadero EX6 that is using the built in REST Client.  I have my RESTClient, SimpleAuthenticator, RESTRequest and RESTResponse controls in place so there isn't any code to show since it’s all done within those controls.  I am not getting a “Not Authorized” return error so I think the API key and authorization is setup correctly.  However I am getting the following response back when I run a query for users.  The RESTRequest is using POST.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Empty field name"}]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I was able to get this working!  I used the built in REST Debugger application within Embarcadero and copied to controls to the clipboard and pasted them into my application.  I found out that the Params in the RESTRequest was causing the issue, there shouldn't be any and also changed the method to GET.

Answer (score 0):

POST is (generally) for creating, so you need to specify the fields of the resource you want to create. In this case to *retrieve* users you want to use a GET.